# Product of discrete random variable with constant

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Say that we have a random variable $X$ and the distribution $P_X$.

I know that is $X$ in continuous then, from the principle of conservation of probability, we get

$P_{cX} = \frac 1 {|c|} P_X(\frac . c)$

Now assume that $X$ is discrete. Do we get the same rule? Since we have deltas and not area the probability mass can be conserved no matter how dense the deltas get, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's right.   For a discrete distribution there's no scaling involved in such change of variables; because all point outcomes have a probability mass.

$$p_{cX}(z) ~=~ \mathsf P(cX= z) ~=~ p_X(z/c)$$

Suppose the support of $X$ is $\{x_i\}_{i\in\Bbb N}$

$$\sum_{{i\in\Bbb N}} p_{cX}(cx_i)~=~1~=~\sum_{{i\in\Bbb N}}p_X(x_i)$$

Comment: Thank you! Having a straightforward answer for such things is just nice.